# \includegraphics Package inputenc error and Undefined control sequence

Tags: includegraphics

**EDIT:
The solution to my problem was editing the graphicspath to: 
\graphicspath{‪{images/}}
**

I am trying to include a figure but I'm getting a myriad of error messages for the same line of code. 
My preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    %backend=biber,
    natbib=true,
    style=numeric,
    sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referenzen.bib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{‪C:/Users/user/Desktop/Latexgrob/images/}
```

Calling the figure:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{lightresponse.jpg}
\caption{Schematisches Diagramm der Photosyntheserate}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The error log says:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
! Undefined control sequence.\GenericError #4 \errhelp \@err@
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed.
!Undefined control sequence.\GenericError... \let \@err@
!Undefined control sequence.\GenericError....\@empty \def \MessageBreak
```

and so on. I attached a picture with all of them. File compiles just fine without the picture. Could someone help me?
[image]

Comment: I bet your real user name is not "user" but contains some non-ascii char. Better remove the `\graphicspath{‪C:/Users/user/Desktop/Latexgrob/images/}` and put the graphic is some better place. Btw: there is a brace level missing in the graphicspath command.

Comment: also if you do use graphicspath you need a brace group around the path `\graphicspath{{‪C:/Users/user/Desktop/Latexgrob/images/}}` but your document would be more portable if you just used a relative path from your main document

Comment: @UlrikeFischer
Hey, thanks for your answer! When I check the properties of the folder, the Users/user/ thing is indeed the given directory path.
I added one more brace on each side to the graphicspath command but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: is is really "user" or is there your real name?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
I added one more brace on each side, but it didn't help unfortunately. Could you give me an example for a "relative path from my main document"? Not really sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer
It really is "user", not my real name. Maybe because I bought the PC used and never changed it, not sure. 
I double-checked, the path seems fine.

Comment: I mean, if your document is in ‪C:/Users/user/Desktop/Latexgrob then your graphicspath need only be `\graphicspath{{images/}}` which means that you can move your document to another machine and it will still work without having machine-specific paths in the code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
Oh, i was not aware of that. Funnily enough that actually solved my problem, no error messages any longer and the picture is perfectly visible. Thank you!
But how is that possible? I'm sure the path in the original version was correct.

Comment: well, latex thinks it was badly encoded, using code that I wrote, so naturally I will believe it, but hard to say given the information posted.

Comment: There is (was) an invisible char before the C (U+202A) in the graphicspath argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I copy & paste your graphicspath command and inspect it with an editor that can show invisible unicode chars (in this case with winedt) I see this:

[image]

The `U+202A` (left-to-right embedding) is the problem.

Removing this char (by deleting the surrounding chars and retyping) and adding the missing braces should resolve the problem

```
 \graphicspath{{C:/Users/user/Desktop/Latexgrob/images/}}
```

As the main document is in Latexgrob it is much better so use a relative path:

```
 \graphicspath{{images/}}
```